# InteractionDefinition not valid ObjectType [Python FuelSDK]

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap, fuel-sdk, python

I am trying to get my journey objects via the API, however I get:

`Message: Error: InteractionDefinition is not a valid ObjectType.`

I am using the python Fuel-SDK. I do not understand why this Object Type is not Valid it seems to be defined in the WDSL file, like all the other objects I can get(). Is this Object not retrievable?

Here's the soap:

`<SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <wsse:Security mustUnderstand="true">
         <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>*</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>*</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
      <etns:oAuth>
         <oAuthToken>*</oAuthToken>
      </etns:oAuth>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <ns1:Body>
      <ns0:RetrieveRequestMsg>
         <ns0:RetrieveRequest>
            <ns0:ObjectType>InteractionDefinition</ns0:ObjectType>
            <ns0:Properties>Name</ns0:Properties>
            <ns0:QueryAllAccounts>true</ns0:QueryAllAccounts>
         </ns0:RetrieveRequest>
      </ns0:RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That object is not retrievable. The InteractionDefinition in the WSDL is basically an abstract type, you wouldn't act directly on it, instead you would act on its subtypes such as SendDefinition or Campaign.  It is not related to Journey Builder interactions.